# DevExtreme Autocomplete Custom ItemTemplate

Tags: autocomplete, devextreme

Is there a way to add a header and a footer to a `DevExtreme autocomplete` item template?

Right now I am getting my list from my datasource and is populating the template but that is only with the items, but can't seem to find a way to add a header and footer.

this is my current setup

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Autocomplete()
                              .DataSource(ds => ds.WebApi().Controller("Search").LoadAction("SearchEmployees"))
                              .Placeholder("Search for employees")
                              .MinSearchLength(3)
                              .Height(66)
                              .OnItemClick("onItemClick")
                              .DisplayExpr("source.fullName")
                              .ItemTemplate(@<text>
                                                <div class="media">
                                                    <div class="pr-20">
                                                        <a class="avatar avatar-online">
                                                            <img class="img-circle img-sm" src="#someimage">" title="title"/>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-5">
                                                            <%= source.fullName %> <small>(<%= source.employeeId %>)</small>
                                                        </h5>
                                                        <p>
                                                            <small> Comapny : <%= source.companyName %></small><br/>
                                                            <%for (i = 0; i < hightlights.length; i++) { %>
                                                            <small> <%= hightlights[i].key %> : <%= hightlights[i].value %></small><br/>
                                                            <%}%>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </text>))
```

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/editorsautocompleteautocompleteautocomplete/

Comment: It isn't clear what `header and a footer` means. It looks like the `ItemTemplate` option should help you.

Answer (score 0):

DevExtreme autocomplete does not support headers and footers directly. Your best bet is to add a beginning and ending item in your data source. Add a type property to your items:

[
{
"type": "header",
...
},
{
"type": "data"
...
},
{
"type": "data"
},
{
"type": "footer"
}
]

In your item template check for the type property to style the item accordingly.